# How to access an instance created inside a method

Tags: c#, methods, instance

I'm trying to create a digital books library, where you can add a book, choose a cover, and add information about it (when the user clicks on "confirm" in form2). once you click on the book you added (which now appears on form1), I want 4 labels to show the title, writer, genre and year of publication.

I created 9 instances of the class "Libro"(Book) inside a switch statement (triggered by a counter which increases every time the user adds a book), like this:

```
public void BtnConferma_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form = new Form1();

        switch (form.counter)
        {
            case 1:
                libro1 = new Libro(TxtTitolo.Text, TxtAutore.Text, TxtAP.Text);
                break;
            case 2:
                libro2 = new Libro(TxtTitolo.Text, TxtAutore.Text, TxtAP.Text);
                break;
            case 3:
                libro3 = new Libro(TxtTitolo.Text, TxtAutore.Text, TxtAP.Text);
                break;
            case 4:
                libro4 = new Libro(TxtTitolo.Text, TxtAutore.Text, TxtAP.Text);
                break;
            case 5:
                libro5 = new Libro(TxtTitolo.Text, TxtAutore.Text, TxtAP.Text);
                break;
            case 6:
                libro6 = new Libro(TxtTitolo.Text, TxtAutore.Text, TxtAP.Text);
                break;
            case 7:
                libro7 = new Libro(TxtTitolo.Text, TxtAutore.Text, TxtAP.Text);
                break;
            case 8:
                libro8 = new Libro(TxtTitolo.Text, TxtAutore.Text, TxtAP.Text);
                break;
            case 9:
                libro9 = new Libro(TxtTitolo.Text, TxtAutore.Text, TxtAP.Text);
                break;
        }

        Close();
    }
```

In the form1 class, when I select the book, I want the label to change

```
private void Selezionato1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LibroInfo libroinfo = new LibroInfo();

        LblTit.Text = libroinfo.libro1.Titolo;
        LblAutore.Text = libroinfo.libro1.Autore;
        LblAP.Text = libroinfo.libro1.AnnoPubb;
            
    }
```

the problem is that it tells me libro1 is not instantiated (I believe it happens because it is instantiated inside the switch)

how can I access the instance of "libro" in form1.cs?

thanks

Comment: Libro1 will only be instantiated when/if `BtnConferma_Click` is called AND `form.counter` is 1.

Comment: What calls `Selezionato1`?

Comment: "i believe it happens because it is instantiated inside the switch" , nope. Its almost certainly because it *was not* instantiated inside the switch. switch is not magic, things made due to them dont disappear unexpectedly.

Comment: also your code is crying out for an array or list of libro objects

Answer (score 1):

```
LibroInfo libroinfo = new LibroInfo();
```

This creates a new instance of LibroInfo which overwrites what you did in the switch statement. 
That's why this line is failing. 
    LblTit.Text = libroinfo.libro1.Titolo;

You are creating a new instance of LibroInfo which has a null libro1 value by default

Comment: Okay, but why is it null? i instantiated libro1 inside the switch (when i click a button), so it shouldn't be null

Answer (score 0):

use a list:

make a class for your book that holds the strings you want to show,  then

```
    public class Book(){
        public string title{get;set;}
public string author{get;set;}
public string genre{get;set;}
public string year{get;set;}

public Book(string tit,string authr, string gen, int pub ){
this.title=tit;
this.authr=author;
this.genre=gen;
this.year=pub;
}

    }
```

in your main class, create list, create books add books to list;

```
  List<Book> books = new List<Book>();

Book newbook = new Book("Eye of the world","Robert Jordan","Fantasy",1990);

books.Add(newbook);
```

now your list is easy to iterate over with a foreach, or can be adapted to a listview for easy sorting.

you can write out a CSV file and save it for persitance, but once you add several books your goin to want a database, or it could possibly be done with a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary to implement this.

Add these fields to your form:

```
Dictionary<int, Libro> _libros = new Dictionary<int, Libro>();
int _seed = 0;
```

Add a method to create new libros. The method increments the seed (id) and adds a new libro to the dictionary:

```
public void NuevoLibro(string titolo, string autore, string annoPubb)
{
    var libro = new Libro(titolo, autore, annoPubb);
    _seed++;
    _libros.Add(seed, libro);
}
```

When the libro is selected on the interface, retrieve the selected Id somehow and get the libro from the dictionary:

```
public void Selezionato1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Something in your GUI will have the id of the libro. Get that id and pull the libro out of the dictionary.
    var id = GetSelectedId();

    //Pull the libro from the dictionary
    var libro = _libros[id];

    //Populate the view
    LblTit.Text = libro.Titolo;
    LblAutore.Text = libro.Autore;
    LblAP.Text = libro.AnnoPubb;
}
```

Please note this code is not thread safe (specially the seed) and should be used for educational purposes only. :-)